# Put JSON keys in a shell script array

Tags: arrays, json, linux, bash, shell

I need to put the json keys of a file as a array in a shell script how can i do that?

```
{
  "employee4" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  },
  "employee3" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  },
  "employee" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  },
  "employee2" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

I need to have a array like keys["employee", "employee2", "employee3", "employee4"]
If there is more keys the array need to find them

Comment: What have you tried so far ? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, you should have a look at `jq`

Comment: i have tried some things but i'm not a expert in jq so i didn't have much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jq` `keys` function returns a list of keys. So with your example data in `data.json`, we see:

```
$ jq 'keys' data.json
[
  "employee",
  "employee2",
  "employee3",
  "employee4"
]
```

To get rid of the JSON list, we run:

```
$ jq -r 'keys[]' data.json
employee
employee2
employee3
employee4
```

And to get that into a `bash` array:

```
myarray=( $(jq -r 'keys[]' data.json) )
```

---

As @glennjackman mentions in a comment, the above construct will have problems if your keys contain whitespace or shell special characters. For example, given this data:

```
{
  "employee*" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

If your directory contains *files* named `employee1` and `employee2`, then you'll get, effectively:

```
myarray=( employee1 employee2 )
```

...which is not what you want. You can fix this by using the `mapfile` builtin (also known as [`readarray`](https://ss64.com/bash/mapfile.html), which makes its purpose more obvious):

```
mapfile -t myarray < <(jq -r 'keys[]' data.json)
```

Comment: Safer to do `mapfile -t myarray < <(jq -r 'keys[]' data.json)` -- any globbing chars or whitespace in the key strings won't get expanded this way.

Comment: @glennjackman you are of course correct, and I've updated the answer with an extended explanation and your solution.

Comment: Might suggest showing the better practice first, if the bad-practice form has a reason to be demonstrated at all? (`array=( $(command) )` is [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29))

Answer (score 0):

The JSON-parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) can do what you want.

To return the JSON keys / attributes:

```
$ xidel -s input.json -e '$json()'   # or -e 'map:keys($json)'
employee4
employee3
employee
employee2
```

To create the Bash array:

```
$ mapfile -t myArr < <(xidel -s input.json -e '$json()')
```

Alternatively, `xidel` can do this too with `--output-format=bash`:

```
$ eval "$(xidel -s input.json -e 'myArr:=$json()' --output-format=bash)"
```

In both cases this will result in:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${myArr[*]}" ${#myArr[*]} ${myArr[0]} ${myArr[1]}
employee4 employee3 employee employee2
4
employee4
employee3
```